# What is a good icon for a 'change units' button?

Tags: icon, pixel-art

We are working on a software with a design close to Office 2013 (2D icons, main colors black and white).

We have a button which allows the user to change the units in the software. We are looking for an icon explicit for users. Units in this case are temperatures : °C, K, °F, but also distances : meters or foot.

What would be a good icon to represent this button? Our problem is that the icon must be `16x16` pixels. We just have no idea what to represent.

Currently it is not explicit:

[image]

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commonality between the units in this case is that they are normally both defined over a scale.

- Short distances are measured with a ruler, that has a scale from one end to the other
- Large distances with a scale on a map
- Thermometers have a scale on them too.

I would therefore show some kind of graduated scale.

[image: Scale]

Comment: That looks to me like "use this to get a measurement of something," not "convert your existing measurement into some other unit."

Comment: good idea put two different scales side by side or the arrow thing on top

Answer (score 4):

Double-headed arrow.

16px version:

[image: arrow1]

100px version for clarity:

[image: arrow2]

Different style, 16px:

[image: arrow3]

100px:

[image: arrow4]

Comment: @Antoine Il n'y a pas de quoi. :)

Comment: I like your second proposal better than the first: that one reminds me of margins or document width a bit too much.

Comment: so translate scale becomes swap. nice.

Answer (score 1):

For t you can combine all three symbols in one icon, or alternatively create 3 icons - each one is activated when proper scale is chosen:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Probably it is better to separate t and l to two different icon/options

Comment: It could be a good idea but it's not possible here. I'm looking for a general "units" icon (l & t). We can't change the icon.